# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, java-21

I am working on an existing old spring-boot code while migrating/upgrading to spring-boot 2.7.16 and jdk version upgraded from 8 to 21 I am getting this error

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;
public class CustomJDBCCall extends SimpleJdbcCall {
private final CustomCallMetaDataContext callMetaDataContext;
private static final String CALL_META_DATA_CONTEXT = "callMetaDataContext";
private static final String MODIFIERS = "modifiers";
private static final Logger LOGGER =Logger.getLogger(CustomJDBCCall.class);

public CustomJDBCCall(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) throws Exception {
    super(jdbcTemplate);
    try {
        callMetaDataContext = new CustomCallMetaDataContext();
        
        // Access private field
        Field callMetaDataContextField = 
        AbstractJdbcCall.class.getDeclaredField(CALL_META_DATA_CONTEXT);
        callMetaDataContextField.setAccessible(true);

   
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField(MODIFIERS);
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(callMetaDataContextField, 
     callMetaDataContextField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);


        callMetaDataContextField.set(this, this.callMetaDataContext);
      } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while using custom JDBC", ex);
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception thrown overriding 
     AbstractJdbcCall.callMetaDataContext field", ex);
     } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while using custom JDBC", ex);
        throw ex;
     }
   }

    public List<SqlParameter> getParamerters() throws Exception {
    return this.callMetaDataContext.getCallParameters();
    }
 }
```

In this code the exception is thrown in the line

```
 Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField(MODIFIERS);
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2782)

Before it was working fine in jdk 8.
This is existing code not written by me and I think here accessing the private final field and setting the value. Am I correct ?
I think in the Jdk version 12 and above modifying the final and private variable is not possible or disabled is there any work around ?

Comment: Such tricks which try to modify Java classes like `java.lang.reflect.Field` directly using reflection are no longer allowed since Java 9.

Comment: This is am existing code written back in 2017. My task is to migrate this old jdk 8 code to latest jdk21. Is there any work around ?

Comment: Probably not. You'll probably need to rewrite this to use normal inheritance.

Comment: that is the risk of using reflection instead of the public API - internals can and will be changed

Comment: The question is what is `CustomCallMetaDataContext` used for? Just to make the implementation of `public List<SqlParameter> getParamerters()` possible?

Comment: This hack is not even necessary. Since the field is not `static`, it is already accessible after your `callMetaDataContextField.setAccessible(true);`. In other words, just `Field callMetaDataContextField = AbstractJdbcCall.class.getDeclaredField(CALL_META_DATA_CONTEXT); callMetaDataContextField.setAccessible(true); callMetaDataContextField.set(this, this.callMetaDataContext);` would do though I agree with the others saying that you should rethink this approach.

Comment: first it is accessing private field and then making in non final

Comment: Holger, let me use your logic and run my spring-boot and test. thanks

Comment: now I am getting a strange exception. The code was working without any issues in jdk8..     org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Error retrieving database meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

Comment: `setAccessible(true)` serves both, ignoring `private` modifier, as well as `final` modifiers for non-static fields. Your follow-up error is an entirely different problem. Maybe your `CustomCallMetaDataContext` is incompatible to the way the framework works (now), in general.

Comment: To make it non final this code is required, Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField(MODIFIERS);
            modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
            modifiersField.setInt(callMetaDataContextField, callMetaDataContextField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added spring class AbstractJdbcCall.java in the project folder with exact package name.
Then added the below method to return the callMetaDataContext

```
public CallMetaDataContext getCallMetaDataContext() {
    return this.callMetaDataContext;
}
```

Now CustomJDBCCall look like this

```
 public class CustomJDBCCall extends SimpleJdbcCall {
        
 public CustomJDBCCall(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) throws Exception 
  {
      super(jdbcTemplate);  
   
  }

  public List<SqlParameter> getParamerters() throws Exception {
    return this.getCallMetaDataContext().getCallParameters();
  }
 }
```

This solved my issue